# React not rerendering when the state is an empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {JSON.stringify(data)}
      <Buttons data={data} setData={setData} />
    </div>
  );
}

var i = 0;
function Buttons({ data, setData }) {
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={(ev) => {
          //console.log(data);
          setData({ [i]: true });
        }}
      >
        click up
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={(ev) => {
          delete data[i];
          setData(data);
        }}
      >
        click down
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

When the page first renders, it shows an empty object. When I click "click", it displays {"1":true}.
However, when I press click down, the page still shows {"1" : true}, even the if i log the data, it is an empty Object. Why is it not rerendering?

Comment: You are mutating the state directly which is preventing a re-render of the react component.

Comment: You're mutating the state directly; the state's object reference hasn't changed.

Comment: So how do you delete from the state object? When providing an answer, please dont tell just what I did wrong, tell me how to do it right

Comment: Just pass an empty object to `setData`: `setData({})`. If you have multiple key-value pairs and you only want to delete one pair, you can create a new object from the existing object using object destructuring: `{ keyToRemove, ...rest} = state`

Comment: `const { "1": removedKey, ...rest } = data;` - `rest` will be the object that you should pass to `setData()`.

Comment: ```<button onClick={ev=>{
  const { i, ...rest} = data;
  setData(rest)
}}
>click down</button>
</>
```
I set the onClick for the delete button to this, and the problem still remains

Comment: Two problems: 1. You need to wrap `i` in square brackets: `[i]`. 2. You need to rename the destructured property name, choose a valid identifier name: `[i]: removedKey`. Change your destructuring code to: `const { [i]: removedKey, ...rest} = data;`

Answer (score 3):

your approach is valid if you make a copy first from your object:

```
const nextData = { ...data }
delete nextData[i];
setData(nextData);
```

you could also destructure your `data` if you prefer as:

```
const { [i]: removed, ...nextData } = data;
setData(nextData);
```